# Help constructing a continuous function to prove whether a set is open or closed

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have the space $M=\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$

the distance function $d(a,b)=\sum\frac{2^{-n}|a_n-b_n|}{1+|a_n-b_n|}$

and the subset $V=\{a \in M|\{n \in \Bbb N|a_n \neq 0\}finite\}$.

I'm trying to find a continuous function $f:M\rightarrow Y$ s.t. $Z\subset Y$ and $f^{-1}(Z)=V$

I think the set would be $(-\infty,0) \cup(0,\infty)$ but i can't figure out how to construct the function itself...

Comment: 1. your distance function doesn't make sense, maybe your sum should be outside the fraction; 2. what is $Y$?

Comment: @KennyLau you're right ! the sum was meant to be outside the fraction. about Y though it doesn't matter what Y is I just want a function so that the inverse image of Z will give me V. and I think that Z is that set $(0,\infty)\cup(0,\infty)$

Comment: take $Y$ to be two points with the discrete topology. map $V$ to one point and $M \setminus V$ to the other point.

Comment: so what would that look like put into notation.for example we could say a continuous function f:\Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R, (x,y)\rightarrow xy. how would we right the function you have suggested in this way ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the indiscrete topology.

Comment: @KennyLau the indiscrete topology has only two members...I'm not sure if you understand what im asking here. I want to find a continous function f so that i can use the fact that Z is open or closed to prove that f^{-1}(Z)=V is open/closed

Comment: I don't quite understand what the question says. Are $Y$ and $Z$ at our disposal? Why can't you take $Y=M$, $f$ the identity map and $Z=V$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes Y and Z are at our disposal. I don't know exactly why you couldn't do exactly what you're saying but it doesn't sound right (it seems too easy..) I'm no expert so I can't say why though.I just basically want to use the theorem which states that if f:X\rightarrow Y is a continuous function and Z\cupY is open/closed Then f^{-1}(Z) is open/closed to show that V is open or closed as was done here  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867600/finding-a-continuous-function-to-show-that-this-set-is-open-or-closed#2867608

Comment: @exodius I don't understand where the question of $V$ being closed comes in. It is not required that $Z$ is closed so its inverse image also need not be closed. I don't think the question has anything to do with any set being closed. I think my example is correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The only thing I'm trying to show is that V is open or closed...

Comment: @exodius I now see that point in your title but you should have included that in the body of the question. Please state what you want carefully in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer.

If $a \in V$ then let $a_n(k)= \begin{cases} a(k),& k \le n \\
1, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. Note that $a_n \notin V$ and $a_n \to a$. Hence $V$ is not open.

Let $e(k) = 1$ for all $k$, and let $e_n(k)= \begin{cases} 1,& k \le n \\
0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. Then $e_n \in V$ for all $n$ and $e_n \to e$,
but
$e \notin V$. Hence $V$ is not closed.

Comment: would you mind elaborating a little bit ? 1. are you saying this is not an answer because you haven't used a continuous function to show this 2. Is it impossible to find a continuous function because it is both open and closed ?3. would your answer gain me full marks on an exam ?

Comment: Well, 1. I'm not sure if $V$ is the set you had in mind, if it is then it is neither open not closed. 2. If $V$ is the set in question, then it is not clear how you could use the inverse function of an open/closed set to show what you want. 3. If the question is to show that $V$ is neither open nor closed then my answer is a valid proof, however your examiner may have other considerations so I can't really answer 3.